# php explode between two delimiter and delimiter not lost

Tags: php, regex, explode

how to explode string between delimiter "[" but i want delimiter not lost
in example i have string like this

```
$str = "i want to show you my youtube channel : [youtube id=12341234] and my instagram account : [instagram id=myingaccount213]
```

i want result like this

```
  [0]=>
  string(61) "i want to show you my youtube channel : [youtube id=12341234]"
  [1]=>
  string(68) "and my instagram account : [instagram id=myingaccount213]"
```

if i use `$tes = explode("]", $content);` the "]" is lost

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot use a different delimiter? E.g: $str = "i want to show you my youtube channel : [youtube id=12341234] | and my instagram account : [instagram id=myingaccount213]".

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I think particular reason is a BBCode (bulletin board code) in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you could also match the parts that you want by matching  optional horizontal whitespace chars, and then capture in group 1 as least as possible chars followed by matching `[...]`

For the matches get the group 1 value using `$matches[1]`

```
\h*(.*?\[[^][]*])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u4wdg5/1/) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/ASnWi)

Example code

```
$s = "i want to show you my youtube channel : [youtube id=12341234] and my instagram account : [instagram id=myingaccount213]";
preg_match_all("~\h*(.*?\[[^][]*])~", $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => i want to show you my youtube channel : [youtube id=12341234]
    [1] => and my instagram account : [instagram id=myingaccount213]
)
```

Another option is making the pattern a bit more specific for youtube or instagram:

```
\h*(.*?\[(?:youtube|instagram)\h+id=[^][\s]+])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JhxcIO/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the string will only contain one

```php
$newStr = substr($str, strpos($str, '[') -1, strlen($str) - strpos($str, ']');
```

or

```php
preg_match('/\[.+\]/', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$str = explode('|', str_replace('] ', ']|', $str));
```